# Position of <use> svg path

Tags: html, svg, position

I need to position an icon path that I got from somewhere on the internet (soon to be replaced with my own). My first attempt using `<symbol>` in conjunction with `<use>` doesn't give me what I want despite significant tinkering (the icon won't get inside the square in the example below). Then I found that using `<g>` instead of `<symbol>` will do the trick, but at the cost of manually scaling the path myself. Since automatic scaling is nicer, there should be a way to position accurately with `<symbol>`.

The [W3 specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#UseElement) mention the different behaviors of `<use>` depending on whether the reference is `<symbol>`, `<svg>`, or otherwise, but that flies right over my head.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Icon won't get in box</title>

<body>
<svg>
<defs>
<symbol id="backward" viewBox="0 0 477.175 477.175"><path d="M145.188,238.575l215.5-215.5c5.3-5.3,5.3-13.8,0-19.1s-13.8-5.3-19.1,0l-225.1,225.1c-5.3,5.3-5.3,13.8,0,19.1l225.1,225 c2.6,2.6,6.1,4,9.5,4s6.9-1.3,9.5-4c5.3-5.3,5.3-13.8,0-19.1L145.188,238.575z"></path></symbol>
<g id='back2' transform='scale(.062)'>
<path d="M145.188,238.575l215.5-215.5c5.3-5.3,5.3-13.8,0-19.1s-13.8-5.3-19.1,0l-225.1,225.1c-5.3,5.3-5.3,13.8,0,19.1l225.1,225 c2.6,2.6,6.1,4,9.5,4s6.9-1.3,9.5-4c5.3-5.3,5.3-13.8,0-19.1L145.188,238.575z"></path>
</g>
</defs>

<g transform='translate(50,50)'>
<rect height='30' width='30' fill='#DDD' />
<use xlink:href='#backward' height='30' x='0' y='0' />
</g>

<g transform='translate(50, 100)'>
<rect height='30' width='30' fill='#DDD' />
<use xlink:href='#back2' x='0' y='0' />
</g>
</svg>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add `width="30"` to your `<use>` reference.

```html
<svg>
<defs>
<symbol id="backward" viewBox="0 0 477.175 477.175"><path d="M145.188,238.575l215.5-215.5c5.3-5.3,5.3-13.8,0-19.1s-13.8-5.3-19.1,0l-225.1,225.1c-5.3,5.3-5.3,13.8,0,19.1l225.1,225 c2.6,2.6,6.1,4,9.5,4s6.9-1.3,9.5-4c5.3-5.3,5.3-13.8,0-19.1L145.188,238.575z"></path></symbol>
<g id='back2' transform='scale(.062)'>
<path d="M145.188,238.575l215.5-215.5c5.3-5.3,5.3-13.8,0-19.1s-13.8-5.3-19.1,0l-225.1,225.1c-5.3,5.3-5.3,13.8,0,19.1l225.1,225 c2.6,2.6,6.1,4,9.5,4s6.9-1.3,9.5-4c5.3-5.3,5.3-13.8,0-19.1L145.188,238.575z"></path>
</g>
</defs>

<g transform='translate(50,50)'>
<rect height='30' width='30' fill='#DDD' />
<use xlink:href='#backward' width="30" height='30' x='0' y='0' />
</g>

<g transform='translate(50, 100)'>
<rect height='30' width='30' fill='#DDD' />
<use xlink:href='#back2' x='0' y='0' />
</g>
</svg>
```

When the width is not set, it defaults to 100% and the symbol is being centred in that 100% x 30px viewport.  You can see that if we add an outline representing that box.

Here "100%" means 100% of the SVG width. That value is 300px, which is the default width that browsers give to elements of indeterminate width.

```html
<svg overflow="visible">
<defs>
<symbol id="backward" viewBox="0 0 477.175 477.175"><path d="M145.188,238.575l215.5-215.5c5.3-5.3,5.3-13.8,0-19.1s-13.8-5.3-19.1,0l-225.1,225.1c-5.3,5.3-5.3,13.8,0,19.1l225.1,225 c2.6,2.6,6.1,4,9.5,4s6.9-1.3,9.5-4c5.3-5.3,5.3-13.8,0-19.1L145.188,238.575z"></path></symbol>
</defs>

<g transform='translate(50,50)'>
<rect height='30' width='30' fill='#DDD' />
<use xlink:href='#backward' height='30' x='0' y='0' />
<rect width="100%" height="30" fill="none" stroke="red" />
</g>

</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like the symbol was created with an SVG editor like Inkscape, but then not properly cleaned up. Especially for such a simple symbol, I don't see any reason at all to be using cubic-Bezier curves with up to 7 decimal places of precision.

I would suggest re-working the symbol to vastly simplify its SVG code. For a basic arrowhead like that you could even just use a `<polyline>` element. A properly-defined symbol will be vastly easier to `<use>` (yay puns!)

Comment: I thought I would use this as a placeholder while working on other things. Besides, my own SVG path may well have the same issue. I don't know how to "clean up," either, and besides do you really believe my problem has to do with what's inside the `<path>`? (I doubt it, since the path works as it should with my second method.)